# Fill forms in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, macros, fill

I'm currently a student in Software Engineering, and I'm trying to create a small program (I don't know if the word "macro" is appropriate for it) in HTML or JavaScript, to fill a form from a webpage.

The webpage has the following code, placed in the **head** section:

> input type=password name=**code** size=8 maxlength=8
>
> input type=password name=**nip** size=8 maxlength=8
>
> input type=password name=**naissance** size=8 maxlength=8

I've been thinking of maybe using JQuery, as I've browsed a little bit on the internet to figure out how to do it, but I don't really know how to do that. I'm pretty sure the only way to do it is to modify the values of the fields "code", "nip" and "naissance", but how do I get access to them from an external file?

Please note that I have bases in HTML and JavaScript, but nothing amazing - I'm still learning :/

Comment: So for starters a good HTML page won't put any display elements in the <HEAD> section as that's rather wrong. Next, jQuery would definitely be helpful here, but maybe since you're learning you can tell us what you've come across that you think would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking to use jQuery, this might be a good place to start:

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Next might be a good tutorial in jQuery to get you started. I'm going to assume you can find those on your own, and I'm going to jumpstart your work:

```
var selector = 'input[name="code"]'; // <-- we define the element we want to find here
// we will use that to select a jQuery element like this -->    $(selector)
$(selector).val('CODE!!'); // <-- it's just that easy to set a value.
```

So if that's what it takes to set the value for `code` from javascript, you can guess what the other two would look like. I'll give you a hint on the second one:

```
$('input[name="nip"]').val('NIP!!');
```

Of course, all this assumes you *do* use jQuery in the browser to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is simply accessing the fields from javascript. You can include any external javascript on the HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://someexternalurl.com/js/jsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

Then in this javascript file you can access the elements as:

```
alert(document.getElementByName("nip").value);

document.getElementByName("nip").value = "abc";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah but it's not from MY page.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish you project by going through this links

[w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

[tizag](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/)

[jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/)

[jquery](http://jquery.com/)

Go through this links

with regards

**Wazzy**